# Does calling a stored procedure from PHP code prevent SQL injection?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, sql-injection

I am very confused about stored procedures, and how to use them to prevent SQL injection. Everything I am reading online seems contradictory and each place gives one example which doesn't seem to work.

Is this, or is this not, secure from SQL injection?

```
PROCEDURE user_get_by_id (IN user_id INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT id, email, name, password_hash FROM users WHERE id=user_id;
END
```

Some tests I have run...
It works with ids that are ints...
It works with ids that are ints as strings...
It says something about fields if I use a string - but I just want it to recognize it is not an int? I tried using a string that is a field, and got the same error.
I used a string with a simple insertion injection (I will do work to test others)
E.G.

```
CALL user_get_by_id(4);
CALL user_get_by_id('4');
CALL user_get_by_id('4; INSERT INTO users () VALUE ();'); (I tested the second statement, and ensured it worked as a regular query, but it did not insert when used this way)
```

I will keep testing from my end, but maybe somebody on here knows if I am 99% there or not. thank you for your help!

I should mention that there is a PHP script which will call the procedure and will use user input.

It will be something similar to...

```
$query = "CALL user_get_by_id(".mysql_escape_string($+POST[id]).")";
```

Reason this question is different than the proposed similar question:

1. the offered response is different ways of crafting PHP code that is SQL injection safe, but this question is about another method using stored procedures and that is NOT provided in that question. Additionally, the answers in that question were not to my liking. Otherwise I would have used that thread when i came upon it the first, second, or third time.
2. this question is not a general how to question - this question is targetted, and specifically asks for advice. I think it is unreasonable to close a specific question by marking it the same as a general question (E.G. If someone is confused about why their math equation isn't working, it makes sense for the respondent to point out why, not mark the question as closed and direct them to a free online math course)

Comment: Sql injection is a vulnerability of data access layer that dynamically constructs sql to execute from user-input, the procedure is not susceptible in this scenario; there are many good arcticles about sql injection and how to correctly use parameters in your data-access layer.

Comment: The call in the php script is akin to...
$query = "CALL user_get_by_id($_POST['id'])";
This is a very simple example, there will be other stored procedures that have multiple parameters.
However I find the simplest minimally reproducable example is the best place to start. this might later a query that returns a password hash when given an e-mail for example...
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Where would this string come from: `'4; INSERT INTO users () VALUE ();'`? It should return one row by the way.

Comment: Yes - and an insert would return no rows - in the same way that the ID may not exist and return no rows.

The goal is to know if this is vulnerable.
I should also state that I will use the string escape function on the POST inputs as well - not just use them directly. Otherwise someone could very easily mess around with the input query.

Comment: technically it's safe. It doesn't mean, however, that it should be used as a protection measure.

Comment: Does mysql_escape_string mean that your PHP version is 5.x?

Comment: I appreciate the question. It is PHP 8.2.
I think the PDO syntax is VERY long and involved.
the single line "mysqli_query($database, $query);" is significantly more readable.
I have no dynamic SQL procedures.
As long as this is safe when the parameters are all just values then I am happy.

Comment: You're overthinking

Comment: in 8.2 you can NOT use mysql_escape_string. in 8.2 you can write `mysqli_execute_query($mysqli, "SELECT id, email, name, password_hash FROM users WHERE id=?", [$_POST['id']])->fetch_assoc();` in one row, which is **NOWHERE** even close to that monster of a stored procedure of yours in being " long and involved". In PHP versions below 8.2 you can easily write a substitute for this function.

Comment: ...as well as for PDO

Comment: Note: with this approach you will have to **alter your database** for the every single query added to application. Like, 100 queries = 100 stored procedures. And when you need a 101th one, another schema change is due.

Comment: @YourCommonSense

There are multiple apps and websites access this database. As things change new queries are written and old queries remain until they are unused. This approach is very solid, and allows for very targetted changes.

I don't think the stored procedure is a MONSTER, but I do like the one line solution you are providing significantly more. Simple, readable, and concise.

Can you provide an example with an int and a string for my sanity? The provided example is (I assume) only for an int.

Comment: the provided example is for everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in fact secure from SQL injection:

```
PROCEDURE user_get_by_id (IN user_id INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT id, email, name, password_hash FROM users WHERE id=user_id;
END
```

By declaring the input argument as type `INT`, any string you try to pass as the argument will be coerced to a numeric value.

In MySQL, the numeric value of a string like '123abc' is 123, and it ignores any following non-numeric characters. A string that has no leading digits, for example 'abc123', has a numeric value of 0.

So it's safe even if you do this:

```
CALL user_get_by_id('4; INSERT INTO users () VALUE ();');
```

The value input to the procedure is simply the `INT` value 4. All the other characters in the argument are eliminated as the argument is cast as an `INT`.

So using the procedure is at least effective at protecting against SQL injection.

However, it isn't the recommended solution, because there are easier methods that don't require a stored procedure.

In PHP, you could cast the POST parameter to an integer value very easily, and either pass this as the value to a procedure:

```
$query = "CALL user_get_by_id({intval($_POST['id'])})";
```

Or even use it directly in a query string:

```
$query = "SELECT id, email, name, password_hash FROM users WHERE id={intval($_POST['id'])}";
```

This is an effective protection from SQL injection for integers, but it does *NOT* work for string or date inputs.

The following is unsafe, because there is no type casting, so there's still a risk that special characters could be copied into the SQL query and cause unintended logic:

```
$query = "SELECT id, email, name, password_hash FROM users WHERE name='{$_POST['id'])}'";
```

You could try to escape the special characters, but that gets confusing.

The solution that is recommended because it is always reliable, simpler, and safer is to use **query parameters.** Query parameters are not simply interpolation into a query string. They keep the dynamic value separate from the query until after it has been parsed, so there is no way the input value can corrupt the intended logic of the query.

```
$query = "SELECT id, email, name, password_hash FROM users WHERE id=?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute( [ $_POST['id'] ] );
```

Query parameters work equally well for both numeric inputs and string inputs.

It's even easier to write the code, read the code, and debug the code when you use query parameters!

Comment: Thank you for the clear and concise answer. I appreciate it!
There were three reasons I used prep over stored procedures...
1. You are right that is very burdensome to make the stored procedures.
2. The PHP would be something like... $query = "CALL procedure([$_POST['param']])";, but that is unsafe. "); drop users; --" would still result in SQL injection, and thus defeats its purpose.
3. There was a simple one line solution for a prepared statement.
mysqli_execute_query($mysqli, "SELECT id, email, name, password_hash FROM users WHERE id=?", [$_POST['id']]), I would be silly not to use it.

Comment: Great, I'm glad this was helpful. For what it's worth, I prefer the PDO interface over mysqli, so I recommend you check it out. PDO has been part of default PHP configurations since version 5.1, so there is no reason not to prefer it.

Answer (score 1):

To have an SQL injection you need 2 programming languages (or a single one that evaluates itself, e.g. with eval). The stored procedure you showed is pure SQL, so there is no way to inject anything.

However, if you call this procedure from PHP then it is possible to have SQL injection. Code like this is vulnerable:

```
$pdo->query('CALL sp('.$_POST['data'].')');
```

When you execute any SQL from PHP, you must use prepared statements. If you remember to never put any PHP variable within SQL then you should be safe from SQL injection.

In PHP, both extensions, mysqli and PDO, offer prepared statements. Make sure you call it like this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('CALL sp(?)');
$stmt->execute([$_POST['data']]);
// or
$mysqli->execute_query('CALL sp(?)', [$_POST['data']]);
```

This is now safe from SQL injection because the SQL string is constant.

Unrelated, but I highly discourage using stored procedures in PHP code. They are very difficult to use and obnoxious. Especially for a simple SQL as you have shown, stored procedure is unsuitable. Don't use stored procedures unless you absolutely must.